# Formatting from the Windows disc

Tags: windows-7, ssd, format

I have HP notebook that has a SSD. I cannot format the disk because the disk can not be seen.

I've tried to use the steps from [Col's answer to Can't install windows 7 on SSD drive](https://superuser.com/a/325406), but in once of the steps it tell me:

> When the welcome screen comes up on Windows Setup, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, which will display a command prompt.

When exactly do I have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>?

Comment: You probably need drivers for your SATA or RAID controller, check out this answer http://superuser.com/questions/494273/dual-boot-windows-8-and-windows-7-why-cant-windows-8-installation-see-the-driv/495031#495031

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> once you see this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Shift+F10 can be pressed from there on, I think it's more useful to use the console right at the partitioning stage than already at the beginning. It may not be needed in the end.