# Windows 8 Installation doesn't detect my SATA Maxtor 6V250F0 HDD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, sata, windows-installation

I've been using Ubuntu on a desktop computer I have in my house and I'd like to try to install Windows 8 and replace the Ubuntu system.

In the installation wizard of Windows 8 I get stuck in the point where I have to specify the HDD to install the OS to. The problem is that I cannot see any hard disk drive to select. I believe this may be related to drivers but I don't know where to get them.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The drivers you need depend on the AHCI/RAID controller your computer has. If you can still access the Linux system running `lspci` in a terminal should output its name, look for the drivers then (if it's Intel look for Intel RST maybe). Then load the drivers during installation, look some here for details: http://superuser.com/q/494273/18050